# Как конвертировать ogg в mp3?

Tags: java, android, аудио, поиск-библиотек, mp3

Как мне можно конвертировать файл формата ogg в mp3? Может есть какая-то библиотека? Просто у меня есть ogg файл, который я получаю, записывая данные с микрофона. Вот так я это делаю:

```
                mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.OGG);
                mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
                try {
                    mRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
                }
                mRecorder.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Сам не пробовал, но попробуйте вот это [https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioConverter](https://github.com/adrielcafe/AndroidAudioConverter) это обертка над [ffmpeg-android-java](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)

Comment: А почему нельзя поменять outputformat на mp3?